# how to separate html tag line by line in php.?

Tags: php, html-parsing

i've a html tags in a php string, how to separate each and every tag from that string ? 
For an Example:

```
$html = '<p><img class="alignnone  wp-image-1665" src="http://doneetjee.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/128a-300x135.jpg" alt="" width="220" height="99" /></p><p>As the belt does not slip,</p><p><img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\therefore&amp;space;\,\,\,\,&amp;space;v_A&amp;space;=&amp;space;v_B" alt="\therefore \,\,\,\, v_A = v_B" align="absmiddle" /></p><p>or';
```

i want the result lke this:

```
"<Image> http://doneetjee.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/128a-300x135.jpg <\Image>
As the belt does not slip,
<Formula> \therefore \,\,\,\, v_A = v_B <\Formula>"
```

Comment: If the input is valid HTML, you should look into using PHP's [DOMDocument](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php)

Comment: it's possible to send the code...!

Comment: I have no idea what you meant by that comment.

Comment: this is my code<?php

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML('<p><img class="alignnone  wp-image-1665" src="http://doneetjee.in/wp-content/uploads/2018/11/128a-300x135.jpg" alt="" width="220" height="99" /></p><p>As the belt does not slip,</p><p><img src="http://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?\therefore&amp;space;\,\,\,\,&amp;space;v_A&amp;space;=&amp;space;v_B" alt="\therefore \,\,\,\, v_A = v_B" align="absmiddle" /></p><p>or');
$xml = simplexml_import_dom($doc);
$images = $xml->xpath('//p');
print_r($images);
foreach ($images as $img)
{
 echo $img;
}

?>

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57374202/edit) your question to include all the relevant code and info. It's pretty unreadable when you write big code chunks in comments.

Comment: im adding the my code in comment

Answer (score 0):

Try adding escape sequence characters like,
\n for new line
\t for tbl space etc.

Example.

Thankyou...

Answer (score 0):

Simple function, just it will replace with \n after every > tag

$html= str_replace(">",">\n",$html);

echo $html;